# Get all members of an AD group with an attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I need to find a way to get all members of an AD group and also with the Mobile Phone number.

This is the command I am using to get the users in the group:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "GROUPNAME" -Recursive |
  foreach {Get-ADUser $_} |
  select name,mobile |
  Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\Groupmembers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

However `mobile` is showing blank fields.

I can't find an answer to get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mobile` attribute is not among the properties that `Get-ADUser` retrieves by default. You need to explicitly request it:

```
... | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser $_ -Properties mobile} | ...
```

Comment: [One can also pipe to `Get-ADUser` directly without the ForEach-Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45323093/1026)