# Get-ADGroupMember to fetch user details?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am using this to fetch all the users in a particular AD group:

```
$names = Get-ADGroupMember -identity "a" -Recursive | select name
```

I am also interested in fetching their corresponding Email Address, is there a way to achieve this via `Get-ADGroupMember`?

I have tried this but this isn't helping:

```
$names = Get-ADGroupMember -identity "a" -Recursive | select mail
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity Administrators -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties *  | Select SamAccountName,mail,EmailAddress
```

Comment: FYI: You can pass the `Get-ADGroupMember` results directly to `Get-AdUser` through the pipeline; `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity Administrators -Recursive | Get-AdUser -Properties mail | select sAmAccountName, Mail`